# Is it a Visual C++ optimizer bug or do I have a bug in my code?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, compiler-bug

We're in the process of migrating from VS2013 to VS2017.

Below is a probably not so minimal code sample, but it's the best I could do.
The gist of it is that a specific float value is sent to a function, but the function receives the wrong value - this is because of a registers mismatch in the calling function.

This code runs **incorrectly** on VC141 (VS 2017) and VC140 (VS 2015), but runs **correctly** on VC120 (VS 2013) and on the clang version which comes built in with VS 2017 (Clang with Microsoft CodeGen (v141_clang_c2) - whatever clang compatible version it is).

The problem manifests when compiling for x64 platform in Release (with optimizations). When removing optimizations the code works fine, so my guess is the optimizer.
The wrong behavior is in `badFunc()` when calling `test()`.

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct FloatWrapper
{
    FloatWrapper() : m_value(0) {}
    explicit FloatWrapper(float value) : m_value(value) {}
    float getValue() const { return m_value; }

private:
    float m_value;
};

class Tester
{
public:

    virtual bool test(FloatWrapper elevation) const
    {
        std::cout << "Expected=" << m_expected.getValue() << ", received=" << elevation.getValue() << '\n';
        return elevation.getValue() == m_expected.getValue();
    }

    Tester(FloatWrapper expected) : m_expected(expected)
    {
    }

    FloatWrapper m_expected;

};

struct DataBlock
{
    FloatWrapper a, b;
};

bool badFunc(const Tester& query, std::vector<DataBlock> blocks)
{
    auto block = blocks[0];

    if (!query.test(block.b))
    {
        std::cout << "Tried to send " << block.b.getValue() << '\n';
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}


int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    DataBlock block;
    block.b = FloatWrapper(0.2f);

    Tester tester(block.b);

    return badFunc(tester, { block }) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Compiler command line:

```
/GS /GL /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /Fd"x64\Release\vc141.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oi /MD /Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Release\" /Fp"x64\Release\compiler_bug_vc14.pch" /diagnostics:classic
```

Linker command line:

```
/OUT:"x64\Release\compiler_bug_vc14.exe" /MANIFEST /LTCG:incremental /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"x64\Release\compiler_bug_vc14.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG:FULL /MACHINE:X64 /OPT:REF /INCREMENTAL:NO /PGD:"x64\Release\compiler_bug_vc14.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"x64\Release\compiler_bug_vc14.exe.intermediate.manifest" /OPT:ICF /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1
```

Comment: This looks like a compiler bug. I could reproduce this on my computer. You should report it to Microsoft.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, report a bug on [connect.microsoft.com](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio).

Comment: Opened an MS connect issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3138251/optimizer-bug-in-vc140-141-passing-the-wrong-float-value-to-a-function

Comment: is this an intermidiate register rounding problem ? if yes, can we consider this really a compiler bug ( or just a quality of implementation issue) ?

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes it's not a rounding issue but using the wrong register when passing the value around.

Comment: wow, do you mean that the to be compared value acquires a totally unrelated value ? that’s frightening ...

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes  Indeed. Good thing it is now fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes - it is an optimizer bug.
Microsoft say they fixed it and it is currently (24 Sep `17) pending release.

See https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/84976/optimizer-bug-in-vc140141-passing-the-wrong-float.html